# How to return values associated with UUID swift

Tags: arrays, swift, data-structures

I have two structs

```
struct ItemModel {
    var itemName: String
    var price: String       
}

struct UserModel {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    var itemModels = [ItemModel]()          
}
```

Is there a way to return the `itemModels` associated with the same `UUID`? I tried this in my `didSelectRowAt` method, however it just returns all `itemModels`.

```
var homeUsers = [UserModel]()

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        Data.itemModels = homeUsers.flatMap {$0.itemModels}
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toItemPageVCSegue", sender: nil)
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: The same UUID as what? What don't you just do `let model = homeUsers[indexPath.row]` then `Data.itemModels = model.itemModels`. Or something similar. This just assumes you have one section in the table where the rows come from `homeUsers`.

Comment: Wow that was a simple solution. Thank you so much!